# Java -Xms and -Xmx test

Tags: java, memory, jvm, runtime

i make a class, Main which contains the main method like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] _args) {
    System.out.println("free:" + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
        + ". max:" + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    }
}
```

then i run the class with -Xms2m and -Xmx2m. the output is like this:

```
free:2984840. max:7471104
```

then, my question is, if a megabytes is 1048576bytes, then the shown free memory is not 2megabytes as set in the -Xms. when i increase the -Xms option to 3m, it shows a megabyte addition free. anyone can explain what is happening,.?

a different case occurs with -Xmx option, when i increase it to 3m, 4m, and 5m, the max is keep showing 7471104. which is around 71.44m. i don't really understand how this two options work.

this is what is printed when i set -Xms3m and -Xmx6m

```
free:4033416. max:7471104
```

anyone can help,.?

thank you :)

notes: i am working with Win7 x64 and Java 1.6 update 35.

Comment: Think this behavior because of you allocate a too small heap. Also it is better to monitor with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html and visual gc plugin. Because behaivior of Runtemie method should depend from JVM implementation.

Comment: I agree @Taky, I set larger values for my application: -Xms100M -Xmx1500M and print result is like this: free:99129720. max:1520435200

Comment: Could you try size like 8, 16, 256, 512 ?

Comment: i set -Xms8m and -Xmx8m, result: free:7834504. max:8060928.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM has restrictions in terms of how memory can be allocated which is not obvious.  This means it only takes the sizes you give it as a hint which will be followed as strictly as it can.  For very small memory sizes these differences are more dramatic but even if you ask for 20 GB it won't be precisely 20 GB to the byte.

Answer (score 0):

The heap not only contains data allocated by your application but also objects allocated by the VM (e.g. objects representing the classes). The Hotspot **VM footprint** is definitely bigger than what you set as max heap size. That is the reason why the actual heap size is bigger.

Comment: setting up Xmx with 2mb, 3mb, 4mb,... show that the maximum around 7mb. then why if 8mb shows exactly 8mb,.? if setting Xmx as 2mb will shows 2mb + extra space, why 8mb shows exactly 8mb,.? hmm,.. still have no idea,..

Comment: could u use `jmap` with `-gcutil` and `-gccapacity`. This will show you exact size/occupation of each heap area. That is more reliable than calling `freeMemory()/maxMemory`.